# Refresh html select with options generated from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to refresh this

```
<div id="refresh_sconto">
    <select id="articolo_sconto" class="col-sm-11" />
        <option value="0"></option>
    <?
        $ids_sconti= $rpc->search("x_sconti","x_company_id.id","=",$_SESSION['company_id']);
        $sconti= $rpc->read($ids_sconti,array(),"x_sconti");

        foreach ($sconti as $key => $sconto) {
            if($sconto['x_tipo']==1)
                echo "<option rel='".$sconto['x_tipo']."H".$sconto['x_valore']."' value='".$sconto['id']."'>".$sconto['x_valore']." - ".$sconto['x_descrizione']."</option>";
            else
                echo "<option rel='".$sconto['x_tipo']."H".$sconto['x_valore']."' value='".$sconto['id']."'>".$sconto['x_valore']." % - ".$sconto['x_descrizione']."</option>";
        }

    ?>
    <option value="new" class="text-danger">--NUOVO-SCONTO--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

with this code:

```
$('#refresh_sconto').load("crea-fattura.php #refresh_sconto");
```

but the select dont work anymore.
I ve a form that make insert a new "sconto" then on the ajax success response i ve to refresh that div.

I really cant figure out the solution :/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("#articolo_sconto select").val("0");
```

this will select your first option.

Comment: Na this dont work for me. Seems that the select dont work anymore but the options are loaded in the right way